# Parametric Estimation of Incomplete survival data/observation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival

Are there other methods besides the Maximum Likelihood for estimating parameters in an incomplete data when a parametric distribution is assumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For instance, one often estimates (the distribution of) parameters for Bayesian models by MCMC sampling. See for instance the textbook [Bayesian survival analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387952772). That's the other major technique I've seen used.